# Как создать кастомный элемент разметки?

Tags: android

Для карточной игры требуется создать элемент, который будет представлять из себя карту (картинку, возможно картинку с текстом), способный реагировать на onTouch в красной зоне (по этому событию запускается Drag and Drop) и на onClick в жёлтой (сброс карты). Подскажите от чего наследоваться (View/ViewGroup/что-то иное) или хотя-бы в каком направлении гуглить?

Может просто использовать FrameLayout и всё? Нарисовать на нём ImageView, и поверх Button, стилизованную под круг с gravity к нижнему левому углу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В итоге использовал FrameLayout, очень удобно и не нужно ни от чего наследоваться. Немного смущает, что вместо одного элемента будет целый layout, но судя по статьям на хабре это не так уж и плохо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего унаследоваться от кого-нибудь из наследников `ViewGroup`, `LinearLayout` например.

Можно почитать [эту](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html) статьи на этот счёт. Так же хорошо бы почитать [офф. док о создании кастомных вьюх](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) и про [обработку тачей](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/making-interactive.html).

Про Drag and Drop тоже есть [офф  док](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) и на vogella [статья](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

Можно вообще отказаться от наследования и рисовать карты на канве элемента `View` растянутого на весь экран. Делал таким образом карточный пасьянс.